# Initialize a vector of customizable structs within an header file

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Is there any way to have a list of global structs and initialize a vector containing modified version of them from within the same header file?
I know I can't directly access and edit variables from an .h file, since it's not run-time code, but maybe there happens to be a workaround to this - or maybe some very basic way that I just happened to skip on the C++ Beginners manual.. pardon me if so!

To make an example, let's say I have a struct which comprehends a couple of members, and declared some global ones in the .h file..

```
struct MyStruct
{
  unsigned int a;
  string foo;
  float myfloat;
};

MyStruct struct_one={1,"hello",0.238f};
MyStruct struct_two={10,"salve",3.14f};
MyStruct struct_three={3,"bonjour",0.001f};
MyStruct struct_four={6,"dias",5.0f};
```

I can then initialize a vector containing them this way (don't know if it's the best  one though)

```
MyStruct MyStructArray[] = {struct_one, struct_two, struct_three, struct_four};

vector<MyStruct> MyStructVector(MyStructArray,
MyStructArray+sizeof(MyStructArray)/sizeof(MyStructArray[0]));
```

But I would like to be able to change, on the fly, some of the structs' members before creating the vector (or the array) without changing the global ones.
Possible?

EDIT: By "within an header file" I meant, "within an header file". If I do `unsigned int a = 100;` in the header, I don't have to initialize or call something in the actual source to make it work. The vector by itself works perfectly, I only wanted to know if there was a way to build it from modified versions of the original global structs.. say, I want to use the same global structs, but with different values for member `a`.

Comment: If you put the definitions of the variables in a header file, then don't. Think what will happen if you include the header file in multiple source files, then you have multiple definitions of the same variables.

Comment: If the globals are in a header file, they better e `extern`, with the initialization in a *single* .cpp file.  And if you're using a compliant C++11 implementation, utilize the joys of [`std::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end). Your `MyStructArray` will have copies of the original structs; not references to them. Therefore, changing `MyStructArray` will not change `struct_one` etc. if that is your concern.

Comment: Well, for now I only have only one .cpp file, so I haven't run into these kinds of problems yet..
Still, how do I use `std::begin()` and `std::end()`? I'm very unfamiliar with them, I must say..

Comment: Look at (4) here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: Isn't this just another way to do the vector building? It doesn't actually help me edit the members.. does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of @Sam 's answer...

**Use a constructor:**

```
struct MyStruct {
    unsigned int a;
    string foo;
    float myfloat;

    MyStruct(unsigned int a, const string& foo, float myfloat) : a(a) , foo(foo), myfloat(myfloat) {}
};
```

Now you can add your struct to the vector with a simple statement

```
vec.push_back(MyStruct(1, "hello", 0.238f));
```

---

```
class Foo {
public:
    static std::vector<int> MyStructVector;
}

inline std::vector<MyStruct> MakeVector()
{
    std::vector vec;
    vec.push_back(MyStruct(1, "hello", 0.238f));
    //...
    return vec;
}

std::vector<MyStruct> Foo::MyStructVector= MakeVector();
```

Comment: Sam's answer apparently disappeared.. it didn't work though, because I still have to call the function to do the work in the .cpp file, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. (Hope it's not too late to respond to the thread)

Comment: @Banderi You can add function in the header file so long as you use the key word `inline` to stop multi definition errors

Comment: But it doesn't work.. if I run the code, it's like nothing in the function has ever happened. Do I have to do something else after `inline`-ing it?

Comment: @Banderi I made an update, I can't test it but that should be all you need in a header file for things to work.

Comment: Oh.. I see! I can't call a function or access an element directly, but I can declare the element as the result of a function in the first place.. That seems to work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if i get your question right:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// Header
// ======

struct MyStruct
{
  unsigned int a;
  std::string foo;
  float myfloat;

  MyStruct(unsigned a, const std::string& foo, float myfloat)
  : a(a), foo(foo), myfloat(myfloat)
  {}
};

typedef std::vector<MyStruct> MyStructs;

extern MyStructs& get_structs();

struct AppendToMyGlobalMyStruct {
    AppendToMyGlobalMyStruct(unsigned a, const std::string& foo, float myfloat) {
        get_structs().push_back(MyStruct(a, foo, myfloat));
    }
};


// Source
// ======

// Have initialization done at first function call, only:
MyStructs& get_structs() {
    static MyStructs s;
    return s;
}

// Another source
AppendToMyGlobalMyStruct a(0, "0", 0);
// Another source
AppendToMyGlobalMyStruct b(1, "1", 1);
// Another source
AppendToMyGlobalMyStruct c(2, "2", 2);

int main()
{
    MyStructs& s = get_structs();
    std::cout << s[0].foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << s[1].foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << s[2].foo << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(names with my are stupid)

Comment: Mm.. no, I'd like to keep all the work in the header file, and I can already easily access global stuff from there without calling it somewhere. I just need to build a vector with structs based on the originals, but not the same.